# Error while executing scikit-learn K-means example

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a scikit-learn K-means example from scikit-learn official site:
http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html#example-cluster-plot-cluster-iris-py

I got all libraries installed (e.g., scipy, numpy, pylab). However, when executing the code, I got error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_cluster_iris.py", line 41, in <module>
    estimators = {'k_means_iris_3': KMeans(n_clusters=3),
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_clusters'
```

Is it something to do with the scikit-learn version? I'm using ver. 0.11 on MAC OS X Lion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking at the docs for the bleeding edge development version of scikit-learn. The stable (0.11) version of that example is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html#example-cluster-plot-cluster-iris-py). `n_clusters` will be introduced in 0.12, in older versions use `k` instead (though `k` will be around for some time for backward compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

you need to upgrade sklern

for updating sklearn you  need
Scikit-learn requires:
    Python (>= 2.6 or >= 3.3),
    NumPy (>= 1.6.1),
    SciPy (>= 0.9).

simply type in terminal(assuming you have installed pip)

pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn